# Gitlab CE 8.11.7 Gitlab-rake issue

Tags: backup, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I'm working with `gitlab ce 8.11.7` from past one month in starting days it worked fine.
But now as I have scheduled cron job for taking complete backup of gitlab server everyday. After running `gitlab-rake` command to take backup my gitlab server is throwing 502 error.
Though all services are up but still it is throwing 502 error.

Please suggest me some solution or suggest any method to take incremental backup of gitlab server.

Answer (score 1):

The "gitlab rake" command you might be refering to would be the ones detailed in "[gitlab-ce/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) "

> Use this command if you've installed GitLab with the Omnibus package:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

> Use this if you've installed GitLab from source:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

As mentioned in [this issue](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/solved-502-gitlab-is-not-responding/258/6), you need to check the logs to know more (like `/var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log`)

Check if `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` help in your case.
As mentioned in "[starting-and-stopping](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/e65f026839594d54ad46a31a672d735b9caa16f0/README.md#starting-and-stopping)":

> Note that on a single-core server it may take up to a minute to restart Unicorn and Sidekiq.
>   Your GitLab instance will give a 502 error until Unicorn is up again.

But upgrading to the latest version (8.14.x) remains one way to get past this error as well.

Comment: im using `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`  this command there is no issue to take backup. but after backup, server is throwing 502 error. and there is only one option is remaining for me that is `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`. But restarting service everyday is not good option.

Comment: Sounds like VonC is saying this is a bug. Upgrade now! 

How large are your backups? I recommend using some options to only backup what you need.

For example, I use this:
`gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=artifacts`

Comment: my server  backup size is almost 5 GB.